# Intersecting problem with rigid bodies

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

There is a mechanism shown in the [figure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcdz4.gif); a rotating gear interacts with a grip.
There is no problem ([figure_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss1TD.gif)) until I change the grip shape with the same setting as previous, where the model crashes ([figure_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5xRs.gif)).
Healthy grip and ill grip settings are shown in [figure_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPeNs.gif) and [figure_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnhp8.gif) respectively.
Grip rotation is due to a hinge constraint. I think the problem is due to that when grip collides with the gear for the first time, it intersects the gear([figure_6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbYLV.gif)).

Therefore the questions are:
1- Why does grip intersects the gear when it collides with the gear for the first time?
2- Is intersecting issue the main cause of the [ill simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5xRs.gif)?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]